# Angular 9 cancel HTTP request

Tags: angular

Angular 9

I want to implement function to cancel api request when user click a button.
I'm using "subscribe" so I thought "unsubscribe()" would work well, but not as I had expected.

this is a stackblitz sample code, which call/cancel api request, and response would be shown in console.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cancel-pending-http-requests-yavvkb

In this code, as below, I called "unsubscribe()" to cancel called request.
Actually after calling "unsubscribe()", soon it reached to add(). but soon after, it received actual API response.

```
export class SearchService {
  private foo: any = null;
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  public getItemList() {    
    this.fetchData();
  }
  public cancel() {
    if(this.foo != null) {
      this.foo.unsubscribe();
      console.log('unsubscribed');    
    }
  }

  private fetchData(){
    const endPoint: string = 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5c245ec630000072007a5f77?mocky-delay=2000ms';
    this.foo = this.apiService.getData(endPoint).subscribe((resp)=>{
      console.log(resp);
    },(err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    }).add(() => {
      this.foo = null;
      console.log('complete');
    });
  }
}
```

output was

> search clicked.
> cancel clicked.
> complete.
> unsubscribed.
> {status: true, statusMessage: "Items fetched successfully", data: Array[10]}.

After cancellation, I don't want to receive response because it's the purpose of "cancel".
But I couldn't figure out how to do.

Thank you for your kind help, in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `takeUntil()` from `rxjs` together with a `Subject`.

I've made an example stackblitz to show this approach: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8vejbb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  private m_unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  private m_fakeObsCallSource: Subject<void> = new Subject();
  private fakeObsCall$: Observable<void> =
    this.m_fakeObsCallSource.asObservable();

  public sendDataToAPI(): void {
    console.log('API call started');

    this.fakeObsCall$.pipe(takeUntil(this.m_unsubscribe)).subscribe(
      () => console.log('API Call returned data!'),
      (error) => {
        console.log('API Call ran into a problem!'),
          () => {
            console.log('API Call completed!');
          };
      }
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.m_fakeObsCallSource.next();
    }, 3000);
  }

  public unsubscribe(): void {
    console.log('Unsubscribed!');
    this.m_unsubscribe.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's just what I want to do

Comment: that did not work for me, did it work for you?

Comment: Can you readd this solution please? It doesnt exists anymore.

Comment: @Kretiss Thank you for the heads-up, I'll update it in a bit.